# I use Next.js v.13 with nextAuth for Keycloak. On localhost it works adequately, but an error comes out on the server '502 Bad Gateway'

Tags: next.js, keycloak, next-auth

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import KeycloakProvider from 'next-auth/providers/keycloak';
import { refreshAccessToken } from '../refreshAccessToken';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      id: 'keycloak',
      name: 'Keycloak',
      clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_SECRET!,
      wellKnown: `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
      issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER,
      checks: ['pkce', 'state'],
      idToken: true,
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          ...profile,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: undefined,
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      if (account && user) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.refreshToken = account.refresh_token;
        token.accessTokenExpired = account.expires_at! * 1000;
        token.refreshTokenExpired =
          Date.now() + (account.refresh_expires_in as number) * 1000;
        token.user = user;

        return token;
      }

      if (Date.now() < (token.accessTokenExpired as number)) {
        return token;
      }

      return refreshAccessToken(token);
    },
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

when I build app and try 'nom start' - all everything works as it should. Вut when I upload to the server - after authorization on keycloak gives an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiVAs.png)

I won't find the place where the error comes from.